# How to write a jquery ui plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to write a jquery ui plugin? I can't find a useful tutorial which will guide me from start. I've never written a plugin for jquery before.

I want to prevent draggables from overlappping on each other. I found a plugin for jquery ui but it doesn't work with version 1.7.1 of jQuery UI

Please help!

Comment: It might be easier to fix the existing plugin to work with 1.7.1.

Comment: For that, I'll have to learn how the plugin system works. :) Any links?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the developer guide.

I believe using the Widget Factory is the recommended pattern.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI_Developer_Guide

Comment: Perhaps moved to http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/stateful-plugins-with-widget-factory/ ?

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery plugin is essentially a collection of function routines.

Have a look here: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

There isn't a definitive *"HOW DO I START WRITING PLUGINS"* section, but the documentation is rather good.

Note: *This: http://www.queness.com/post/112/a-really-simple-jquery-plugin-tutorial may also help*

Answer (score 0):

Jquery in action book can help you. http://www.manning.com/bibeault/